# Query using two different relation laravel

Tags: laravel

I have relations like : a secteur has many sections, a section has many users, so a user belongs to a section and a section belongs to a secteur.

In Secteur model

```
public function sections()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Section::class,'secteur_id');
}
```

In Section model

```
  public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class,'section_id');
}

 public function secteur()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Secteur::class,'secteur_id');
}
```

In User model

```
 public function section()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Section::class,'section_id');
}
```

Now i'm trying to get all the users who belongs to a secteur, for that i need to retrieve all sections from the secteur and all users who belongs to all sections i've got.

I don't know how to do that.

ps:Sorry for my english i'm french

Comment: tu peux me ré-expliquer correctement ton probleme avec un peu de code stp ? genre tes models et migrations

Comment: What is the data structure for your tables?

Comment: I've had some code to be more explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eloquent has a [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship which may be what you want.

On secteur, you can add this:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Section::class);
}
```

As the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) state:

> "The first argument passed to the hasManyThrough method is the name of
> the final model we wish to access, while the second argument is the
> name of the intermediate model."

You can also pass keys as additional arguments if you need to, but the ones you're using above look like the defaults and if they are you can omit them.